# Apache-fineract reporting issue with apache-pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer, apache-fineract

While running a pento report, getting this error.
Setup is done on docker with mariadb-11.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=fineractmysql)(port=3306)(type=primary). Socket factory failed to initialized with option "socketFactory" set to "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory"
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.connectSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:137)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.<init>(StandardClient.java:99)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:70)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:101)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.DriverConnectionProvider.createConnection(DriverConnectionProvider.java:121)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.getConnection(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:130)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:174)
fineract-server_1  |    ... 197 common frames omitted
fineract-server_1  | Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket factory failed to initialized with option "socketFactory" set to "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory"
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.standardSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:100)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.socket.impl.SocketUtility.lambda$getSocketHandler$0(SocketUtility.java:38)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.createSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:69)
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.connectSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:124)
fineract-server_1  |    ... 204 common frames omitted
fineract-server_1  | Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to class javax.net.SocketFactory (com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @5e9f23b4; javax.net.SocketFactory is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
fineract-server_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.standardSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:92)
fineract-server_1  |    ... 207 common frames omitted
fineract-server_1  | 
fineract-server_1  | 2023-09-26 08:57:06.621 -ERROR 8  --- [io-8443-exec-10] i.r.s.PentahoReportingProcessServiceImpl : Pentaho failed
fineract-server_1  | 
fineract-server_1  | org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed to execute query.
```

While running exp0rt report of client oan transaction I got 403 error.

```
{
  "developerMessage" : "The request caused a data integrity issue to be fired by the database.",
  "httpStatusCode" : "403",
  "defaultUserMessage" : "Pentaho failed: Failed to execute query.",
  "userMessageGlobalisationCode" : "error.msg.reporting.error",
  "errors" : [ {
    "developerMessage" : "Pentaho failed: Failed to execute query.",
    "defaultUserMessage" : "Pentaho failed: Failed to execute query.",
    "userMessageGlobalisationCode" : "error.msg.reporting.error",
    "args" : [ ]
  } ]
}
```